# How can I load 'utf8' into plperl by default?

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-extensions, perl, solaris

I am attempting to solve a problem explained in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20355007/13860).  On Debian 7.4 with Postgres 9.1.12, I am able to use the Perl `qr` operator just fine.  On Solaris 5.11 with Postgres 9.2.4, however, I am not able to.

As detailed in the question above, the following stored procedure fails on the Solaris installation:

```
REATE FUNCTION foo(VARCHAR) RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
    my ( $re ) = @_;
    $re = ''.qr/\b($re)\b/i;
    return $re;
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

With the following error:

```
ERROR:  Unable to load utf8.pm into plperl at line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
CONTEXT:  PL/Perl function "foo"
```

It is apparent that in the Debian installation of Postgres, 'utf8' is already loaded by default. I ran the following stored procedure on both systems:

```
CREATE FUNCTION perl_modules() RETURNS VOID AS $$
    warn join(', ',sort keys %INC);
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

On the Debian system:

> WARNING:  Carp.pm, Carp/Heavy.pm, Exporter.pm, feature.pm, overload.pm, strict.pm, unicore/Heavy.pl, unicore/To/Fold.pl, utf8.pm, utf8_heavy.pl, vars.pm, warnings.pm, warnings/register.pm at line 2.

On the Solaris system:

> WARNING:  Carp.pm, Carp/Heavy.pm, Exporter.pm, feature.pm, overload.pm, overloading.pm, strict.pm, vars.pm, warnings.pm, warnings/register.pm at line 2.

I tried to load the `utf8` module on the Solaris system by adding this to the postgres config file:

```
plperl.on_init = 'use utf8; use re;'
```

And that successfully loads the `utf8` and `re` modules, as shown here:

> WARNING:  Carp.pm, Carp/Heavy.pm, Exporter.pm, XSLoader.pm, feature.pm, overload.pm, overloading.pm, re.pm, strict.pm, utf8.pm, vars.pm, warnings.pm, warnings/register.pm at line 2.

However the `foo()` stored procedure still fails:

```
dc=# select foo('foo');
ERROR:  Attempt to reload utf8_heavy.pl aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/perl-5.18.0/lib/utf8.pm line 17.
CONTEXT:  PL/Perl function "foo"
```

What is the secret to successfully loading `utf8`, and its dependencies, in this Solaris environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found involes mimicing the `utf8` module's AUTOLOAD function in the `plperl.on_init` setting:

```
plperl.on_init = 'use utf8; use re; package utf8; require "utf8_heavy.pl";'
```

This successfully loads and initializes the `utf8_heavy.pl` file before dropping into Postgres's safe mode for running perl scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to create the function with `plperlu`.

- [Trusted and Untrusted PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-trusted.html)

This gives it access to use all the modules on the system.